# ECONNREFUSED error when proxying from React to Flask running in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flask, proxy, docker-compose

I've been all over this so finally asking.

I basically have a `flask` API and a `react` front end running on my dev machine.

They are running via `docker-compose` on the same virtual network.

The flask api runs perfectly when I postman to it via the 5000 port and the react front end works perfectly in the browser on port 3000.

I edited the react `package.json` file and added `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

Then when running the route I want from react over on `localhost:3000/movies` it tries to proxy on over to `localhost:5000/movies` but I get this error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /movies from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED)
```

I've tried changing that line to various things including my docker image name. So `proxy": "http://image-name:5000",`  and I've also tried the internal docker network name like `proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",` and they all give the same kind of error.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try beyond that?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is for anyone in the future.

The container name needed to be used.  So I updated my `docker-compose.yml` to have:

```
services:
  flask-api:
    container_name: flask-api
```

In my API (flask app) my config.py was like so:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'localhost:5000'
```

I changed it to:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'flask-api:5000'
```

The react package.json was updated to:

```
"proxy": "http://flask-api:5000",
```

Then on reload `docker-compose build --up` it worked.

The proxy from react forwards to the flask api.  So in my case localhost:3000/movies proxies to locahost:5000/movies to get my api data.

I trust that helps someone in the future.

Comment: Yep. But what if you want to run this without docker. Can anybody think a workaround that works both for docker-compose and standalone developing?